# How to locate Xcode after installation (Xcode beta)?

Tags: ios, xcode, installation, xcode7

I'm new to the world of iOS and have just started learning the technologies used to create iOS Apps. I’ve downloaded Xcode 7 (beta) on my mac (which has an OS 10.10.2). I’ve used the downloaded file (Xcode_7_beta.dmg) to complete the installation using the terminal command (Xcode-select —install). The installation seems to have completed however I’m struggling to locate the installation anywhere with an intention to launch it. Would appreciate some help around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The application will be named **Xcode-beta** and exist in your Applications folder.

This is located just off the root of the drive at: `/Applications`